# Compare two df's and populate value from one df to another

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to compare the `amount_spent` column in df1 and df2 and if the `amount_spent` column in df1 is  `null`  (null is a string not nan) then populate the value from df2 to df1 for that particular `customer_id`.

df1

```
customer_id  amount_spent 
3021         144
0535         042
7532         null 
2131         932
```

df2

```
3021         144
0535         042
7532         945
```

Desired output df

```
3021         144
0535         042
7532         945
```

Comment: Do you need to cross-reference the data by `customer_id`? Or can you blindly just apply the change row by row?

Comment: no cross-reference needed. Just to check if value in row = 'null' (null is a string not nan) and if so then populate value from df2 to df1

Comment: oh sorry to answer your question yes it would have to be based on the customer_id

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"customer_id": ['3021', '0535', '7532'], "amount_spent": ['144', '042', 'null']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"customer_id": ['3021', '0535', '7532'], "amount_spent": ['144', '042', '945']})

null_list = df1.index[df1['amount_spent'] == 'null'].tolist()

for null in null_list:
    df1["amount_spent"][int(null)] = df2["amount_spent"][int(null)]
```

It creates a list with all indices that underly the condition and populates the right value.

Comment: I am getting the following error: ValueError: 213 is not in range

Comment: This might be because df1 has more rows than df2 and therefore its throwing the error above

Comment: @user12625679 you edited your question. They had the same number of rows previously.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"customer_id": ['3021', '0535', '7532'], "amount_spent": ['144', '042', 'null']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"customer_id": ['3021', '0535', '7532'], "amount_spent": ['144', '042', '945']})


df1 = df1.set_index("customer_id")
df2 = df2.set_index("customer_id")
df1.loc[df1['amount_spent'] == "null", 'amount_spent'] = df2['amount_spent']
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print(df1)
```

It gives:

```
  customer_id amount_spent
0        3021          144
1        0535          042
2        7532          945
```